# running qemu on Fedora20

Tags: fedora, virtualization, qemu

With Fedora20 and built from sources qemu-2.1.1, I'm experiencing issues to run qemu with non-root privileges:

```
% qemu-system-x86_64 -hda vdisk.img -m 512M -netdev tap,helper=/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper,id=net0 -device e1000,netdev=net0
failed to create tun device: Operation not permitted
failed to launch bridge helper
qemu-system-x86_64: -netdev tap,helper=/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper,id=net0: Device 'tap' could not be initialized
```

Tun device has proper permissions:

```
% ls -la /dev/net/tun
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 200 Sep 30 09:22 /dev/net/tun
```

qemu-bridge-helper has suid bit enabled, SELinux is disabled ('getenforce' returns Disabled). Whatever else am I missing?

Comment: Try the qemu in your package manager and remove the source...

Comment: Maybe raw sockets require a privilege as well? `strace -f` to see where qemu fails. `setcap cap_net_raw+ep -- "$(which qemu-system-x86_64)"` should give you that privilege, if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way the cookie crumbles with QEMU.  If you read the [documentation](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Tap) you'll get to:

> **Tap**
>
> The tap networking backend makes use of a tap networking device in the host. It offers very good performance and can be configured to create virtually any type of network topology. Unfortunately, it requires configuration of that network topology in the host which tends to be different depending on the operating system you are using. **Generally speaking, it also requires that you have root privileges.**

Running QEMU as a user gives you a simplified networking.  According to a [WikiBooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking#User_mode_networking)

> If no network options are specified, QEMU will default to emulating a single Intel e1000 PCI card with a user-mode network stack that bridges to the host's network. The following three command lines are equivalent:
>
> `qemu -m 256 -hda disk.img &`
>   `qemu -m 256 -hda disk.img -net nic -net user &`
>   `qemu-system-i386 -m 256 -hda disk.img -netdev user,id=network0 -device e1000,netdev=network0 &`
>
> The -net option is superceded by -netdev in newer QEMU versions.
>
> The guest OS will see an E1000 NIC with a virtual DHCP server on 10.0.2.2 and will be allocated an address starting from 10.0.2.15. A virtual DNS server will be accessible on 10.0.2.3, and a virtual SAMBA file server (if present) will be accessible on 10.0.2.4 allowing you to access files on the host via SAMBA file shares.
>
> User mode networking is great for allowing access to network resources, including the Internet. By default, however, it acts as a firewall and does not permit any incoming traffic. It also doesn't support protocols other than TCP and UDP - so, for example, ping and other ICMP utilities won't work.

Comment: so according to http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Tap I have not chance to launch qemu with non-root account? Hm, ok..

Comment: You can run `qemu` as an user, but it will be quite restricted. You could (depending on your situation) set up `sudo` to allow `qemu` to run without a password.

Comment: however when running qemu as a non-privileged user, it is not able to configure tap interface, no matter what permission I set on /dev/net/tun So my conclusion is that I _must_ run qemu as root if I need TAP functionality.

Comment: You can run qemu as a unprivileged user by having qemu drop permissions via `-runas user` or by creating a tap device that is owned by the unprivileged user. `ip-tuntap(8)` can assign ownership of tuns/taps. among other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Fedora 21, but maybe it was already available on Fedora 20

There is a new way to give option to setup bridge connection, which is :

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda vdisk.img -m 512M -netdev bridge,id=net0,br=qemubr0 -device e1000,netdev=net0
```

You don't have to set helper=/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper, it seems the default

And you have to make sure when using the default helper you have 
the file /etc/qemu/bridge.conf with the bridge you intend to use

```
allow qemubr0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of:

```
ls -l /dev/kvm
```

Look at the user-permissions segment, looks something like **user group**

Make sure your user has access to /dev/kvm

```
chown your_user:your_group /dev/kvm
```

Then you can run VMs from your user!

Comment: I don't have troubles with /dev/kvm, permissions on kvm device are correct. The problem occurs when qemu, specifically qemu-bridge-helper attempts to fiddle with tap0 device.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I could solve the problem by setting user-ID bit on execution on the "qemu-bridge-helper":

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/qemu-bridge-helper
ls -la /usr/lib/qemu-bridge-helper 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 14336 Dez 16 15:36 /usr/lib/qemu-bridge-helper
```